# How to append to a list in Terraform?

Tags: list, append, concatenation, terraform

I have some code in the general form:

```
variable "foo" {
  type = "list"
  default = [ 1,2,3 ]
}

resource "bar_type" "bar" {
  bar_field = "${var.foo}"
}
```

I want to append an addition value to `bar_field` without modifying `foo`. How can I do this? I don't see any sort of contacting or appending functions in their docs.

This is 0.11.x Terraform

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#concat-list1-list2-) function for this. Expanding upon the example in your question:

```
variable "foo" {
  type = "list"
  default = [ 1,2,3 ]
}

# assume a value of 4 of type number is the additional value to be appended
resource "bar_type" "bar" {
  bar_field = "${concat(var.foo, [4])}"
}
```

which appends to the value assigned to `bar_field` while ensuring `var.foo` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 8):

Adding new item to the list if not present:

```
locals {

  oldlist = ["a", "b", "c"]
  newitem = "d"

  newlist = (contains(local.oldlist, local.newitem) == false ? concat(local.oldlist, [local.newitem]) : local.oldlist)

}

output "newlist" {
  value = local.newlist
}
```

Comment: Normally you don't test for boolean values (in any programming language) i.e.
`contains(local.oldlist, local.newitem) ? local.oldlist : concat(local.oldlist, [local.newitem])`

Comment: @O.G., Why did you add square brackets to the second `concat` argument? I'm getting errors using a local in concat and noticed your post. TIA.

Comment: Well, simply becouse `local.newitem` is a string type, and `[local.newitem]` converts it to list. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
var1 = ["string1","string2"]

var2 = "string3"

var3 = concat(var1, formatlist(var2))
```